# Sorting listview in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have listview with Title, image and date. I want to sort that list on the basis of date field and then display in html5 page. I used jquery and html5 on this.

```
$j('#task_summary_list').empty();

if (response.totalSize > 0) {
    $j.each(response.records, function(i, record) {
        var imgName;
        switch (record.Priority) {
            case "High":
                imgName = "images/prio_high24.png";
                break;
            case "Low":
                imgName = "images/prio_low24.png";
                break;
            default:
                imgName = "images/prio_normal24.png";
        }

        // create new list entry for record to the listview
        $j('<li></li>')
        .attr('id', record.Id)
        .hide()
        .append(
                '<a href="#">' + '<img src="' + imgName
                + '" alt="High" class="ui-li-icon">'
                + '<h1>'
                + record.Subject + '</h1>'
                + '<p>' + '<strong>'
                + record.ActivityDate + '</strong>' + '</p>'
                + '</a>')
        .click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            console.log("Under onSuccessTasks " + record.Id);
            showTaskDetails(record);
        })
        .appendTo('#task_summary_list')
        .show();
    });
}
else {
    $j('<li class="norecord">No records to display</li>').appendTo('#task_summary_list');
}

$j('#task_summary_list').listview('refresh');

$j.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in avance.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#dateDiv').sortElements(function(a, b){
    return Date.parse($(a).text()) > Date.parse($(b).text()) ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my app I use sql query, so I use OrderBy clause after my main query, and data is in sorted form and easily displayed on UI.

Thanks